# How to create element of XML file with looping using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, loops

Im going to create xml file. The element of the xml I pick from .ini file. I have .ini file more than 1.
I try this, but still can create only 1 element.

There are 2 kind of type content file in my .ini file.
1st.

```
[Product]
Name = NB A
String = Defaults and Exit

[Controller1]
Desc = Embedded Intel RAID

[Controller2]
Desc = Intel Optane Device
```

2nd.

```
[Product]
Name = NB A
String = Defaults and Exit

[Controller1]
Desc = Embedded SATA
```

My expectation output of XML, will be there are 2 type.
1st.

```
<Product Name=NB A>
      <Controller controllertype="raid">
      <Controller controllertype="optane">
</Product>
```

2nd.

```
<Product Name=NB A>
      <Controller controllertype="raid">
</Product>
```

The code I wrote so far :

```
$ProductListXML = "D:\TST.XML"
$driver = "D:\ver.xml" 


# get an XMLTextWriter to create the XML
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($ProductListXML,$Null)

# choose a pretty formatting:
$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
$XmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"

# write the header
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('ProductList')
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('Version', '200422a')

# load it into an XML object:
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($driver)
$FamilyCode = $Xml.drivergroup.family | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Code

foreach ($fc in $FamilyCode)
{
    $FCDesc = $Xml.drivergroup.family | Where-Object { $_.code -eq "$fc" }| Select-Object -ExpandProperty description
    $SystemID = $Xml.drivergroup.family |  Where-Object { $_.code -eq "$fc" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Product | Select-Object -ExpandProperty systemid
    $IDSplit = $SystemID -split "/"

    $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Family')   
    $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('code', "$fc")
    $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('decription', "$FCDesc")

    foreach($sid in $IDSplit)
    {

        $ID = Get-ChildItem -path "D:\product\*$sid*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName

        foreach ($id in $ID)
        {
            $File = Get-ChildItem -path "D:\product\*$id*"
            $ReadINI = @{} 
            Get-Content "$File" | ForEach-Object {
            $_.Trim()
            } | Where-Object {

            $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
            } | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
            $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
            $ReadINI[$section] = @{}
            } else {
            $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
            $ReadINI[$section][$key] = $value    
            }
            }

            $ProductName = $ReadINI["Product"]["Name"]
            $TechType = $ReadINI["Controller1"]["Node"]
            if($TechType -eq "Intel")
            {
                $TechType = "Intel"
            }
            else{

                $TechType = "AMD"
            }
            $FactoryDefaultsString = $ReadINI["Product"]["String"]

            $YearPath = "D:\*.txt"
            $YearMapping = Select-String -Path $YearPath -Pattern "$id" 
            if($YearMapping -like "*2017*")
            {
                $Year = "2017"
            }
            elseif($YearMapping -like "*2018*")
            {
                $Year = "2018"
            }
            elseif($YearMapping -like "*2019*")
            {
                $Year = "2019"
            }
            elseif($YearMapping -like "*2020*")
            {
                $Year = "2020"
            }
            elseif($YearMapping -like "*2021*")
            {
                $Year = "2021"
            }

            $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Product')
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('Name', "$ProductName")
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('SSID', "$id")
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('TechType', "$TechType")
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('Year', "$Year")
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('FactoryDefaultsString', "$FactoryDefaultsString")

            $Controller2 = Select-String -Path $File -Pattern "Controller2" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Filename
            foreach ($cont2 in $Controller2)
            {
                $file = Get-ChildItem "D:\product\$cont2"
                $ReadTechTp = @{} 
                Get-Content "$file" | ForEach-Object {
                $_.Trim()
                } | Where-Object {

                $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
                } | ForEach-Object {
                if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
                $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
                $ReadTechTp[$section] = @{}
                } else {
                $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
                $ReadTechTp[$section][$key] = $value    
                }
                }

                $Desc = $ReadTechTp["Controller2"]["Desc"]

                if($Desc -like "*RAID*" -or $Controller1 -like "*SATA*")
                {
                    $ControllerType = "RAID"
                }
                else{
                    $ControllerType = "OPTANE"
                }

                $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Controller')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('ControllerType', "$ControllerType")

            }


            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

        }



    }


    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
}

    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

# finalize the document:
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

Anyone can help please. Advices and solution really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

- Make a Regex to match headers. This could be something like `^\[(.+)\]$`.

  - Match start of the line with `^`,
  - Finds the first `[` bracket with `\[`,
  - Matches any character once or more in a group with `(.+)`,
  - Matches the last bracket `]` with `\]` and ends the line with `$`.
- Make a Regex to match keys and values. This could be something like `^(.+?)\s*=\s*(.*)$`.

  - Match the start of the line with `^`,
  - Finds keys with any character one or unlimited times with `(.+?)`,
  - Matches zero or more whitespace between an `=` sign with `\s*=\s*`
  - Matches zero or more characters in a group with `(.*)` and ends the line with `$`.

With the above in mind, we can make a function to return the `.ini` file structure as nested hash tables. I use the `-File` and `-Regex` switches from `switch` to read the file and search for regex patterns. You can have a look at [`about_Switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7) for more information.

However, this will probably have to have more error checking, such as dealing with comments and invalid entries. I've just made something that will work for the above `.ini` files.

```
function Get-IniFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$FilePath
    )

    $ini = [ordered]@{}

    switch -Regex -File $FilePath {

        # Match headers
        "^\[(.+)\]$" {
            $section = $Matches[1]
            $ini[$section] = [ordered]@{}
            continue
        }

        # Match key-value pairs
        "^(.+?)\s*=\s*(.*)$" {
            $name, $value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
            continue
        }
    }

    return $ini
}
```

Then you could iterate your two `.ini` files, lets say `first.ini` and `second.ini`. and create the XML files for both of them using the hash tables returned from `Get-IniFile`.

```
$iniFiles = "first.ini", "second.ini"

# Go through each .ini file
foreach ($file in $iniFiles) {

    # Create XML object to write to
    $xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument

    # Get .ini file data into a hashtable
    $iniFileData = Get-IniFile -FilePath $file

    # Iterate first set of keys from hashtable
    foreach ($kvp in $iniFileData.GetEnumerator()) {

        # Create a product root key for the header
        $product = $xml.CreateElement($kvp.Key)

        # Iterate through key-value pairs
        foreach ($value in $kvp.Value.GetEnumerator()) {
            switch ($value.Name)
            {

                # If we found a name, this attribute belongs to the header
                "Name" {
                    $product.SetAttribute($value.Name, $value.Value)
                    $xml.AppendChild($product)
                    break
                }

                # Otherwise we found a descendent node
                "Desc" {

                    # Create descendent controller node
                    $controller = $xml.CreateElement("Controller")

                    # Determine how to set the attributes depending on the value
                    if ($value.Value -like "*RAID*" -or $value.Value -like "*SATA*") {
                        $controller.SetAttribute("controllertype", "raid");
                    } else {
                        $controller.SetAttribute("controllertype", "optane");
                    }

                    # Append controller node to product root node
                    $xml.Product.AppendChild($controller)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # Save to XML file, using the name from the original file
    $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    $xml.Save("{0}.xml" -f $filename)
}
```

**first.xml**

```
<Product Name="NB A">
  <Controller controllertype="raid" />
  <Controller controllertype="optane" />
</Product>
```

**second.xml**

```
<Product Name="NB A">
  <Controller controllertype="raid" />
</Product>
```