# How to create XML file automatically with INI file using Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, loops

I want to create an XML file. I have to pick some information from another XML file and INI file.
This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Group version="111">
    <Class code="WWWC_53307F" note="bPC">
        <Name note="Cubano - Rebuild 1" studentID="872C/8834">
            <major name="rt640x64" />     
        </Name>             
        <Name note="Doppio - Rebuild 1" studentID="872E/8836">
            <major name="rt640x64" version="11182019,10.038.1118.2019" />     
        </Name>     
    </Class>
    <Class code="WWWC_53316J" note="cPC">
        <Name note="Fangio 1.2" studentID="81B7/82DC/81B8/81B9">
            <major name="rt640x64" />
        </Name>
        <Name note="Typhon 1.1 - rebuild 1" studentID="81B6/8268/82E0">
            <major name="asmthub3" />
        </Name>
        <Name note="Willow" studentID="822A/82D7">
        </Name>
        <Name note="Shave Rebuild 1" studentID="2B5B">
    </Class>
</Group>
```

The ini file there are two type. I have more than 1 ini file.

```
[Name]
Name = NB A
String = Defaults and Exit

[Controller1]
Desc = Embedded SATA 

[Controller2]
Desc = Intel Optane Device

[Name]
Name = NB A
String = Defaults and Exit

[Controller1]
Desc = Embedded SATA
```

My expectation output of new XML is like this

```
<Group version="22">
    <Name code="WWWC_53307F" note="bPC">
        <Pro Name="DM System" SSID="8594">
            <Controller ControllerType="Embedded SATA"/>
            <Controller Controllertype="Intel Optane Device"/>
        </Pro>
    </Name>
    <Name code="WWWC_53316J" note="cPC">
        <Pro Name="DM System" SSID="8594">
            <Controller ControllerType="Embedded SATA" />
        </Pro>
</Gr
```

Group>

Anyone can give idea please helpe. Thank you

Comment: Oh I was just about to answer your last question about the INI file but you deleted it.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I just create the simple one to easy to understand. If you don;t mind, can share it here. THank you @RoadRunner

Comment: I would share it but it seems like you want something very different here.

Comment: @RoadRunner I undelete the queestion https://stackoverflow.com/q/61378712/11076819

Comment: How do you get attributes like `Name="DM System" SSID="8594"`? These values are nowhere to be found in the example ini, so how can this info-from-nowhere possibly match `code="WWWC_53307F"` ??